# Composer command not running magento2

Tags: magento2, composer, cli, mailchimp

I am trying to run the following command -

```
composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
```

But I am getting following error on command line -

```
[UnexpectedValueException]                                                                                                
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(extension/mageworx_downloadsmeta): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

I have uploaded the Mailchimp extension via FTP but when trying to load dependencies getting the errors